# How to get changed value dropdown list in datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown, datalist

html code:

```
<asp:DataList  ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:DropDownList ID="listedad" data-max="30"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and my code behind :

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
int tedadkala = Convert.ToInt32(((DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("listedad")).Text);

int gheymat =
 Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblvahed")).Text);

int batedad = gheymat * tedadkala;

((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblhesab")).Text = batedad.ToString();
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblhesab")).DataBind();

    }

    protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    

    }
```

Comment: it only when page load is worcking, but after i change the dropdown list :

Comment: i cant use dropdown_textchange event becuse is in data list, i realy need your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Instead of doing databinding in pageload directly put in in a function , and call it where ever you need to run your ItemDataBound .Like this ..

```
//common function for databound
Public void databind()
{
     DataList1.DataSource = // ypur datasource
     DataList1.DataBind();
} 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {
        databind();
    }
}

//Do the necessary coding in DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged

Protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    //get whatever value you need

    databind();//Call To Function that binds To datalist
}
```

All the time when you bind to datalist then the itembound function will work